# R - Replacing all column values from a given dataset

Tags: r

Greetins,
I am trying to do something simple in R but programming is not my strong.

I need to replace all values from a dataset column `spentDB$M3` to the given value `12`. .
Since the dataset's length for each value goes up to 1:5000 I was thinking in approaching it with a for loop but I am not sure how to write it basically.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Like `spentDB$M3[1:5000] <- 12`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do:

`spentDB$M3 <- 12`

Which will set all values to 12.

Answer (score 0):

If the answer below doesn't work, it would be good to change your column name to some other (https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/rename-data-frame-columns-in-r/) and then use:

```
dataset_name$new_column_name <- 12
```